# Why do we need function_exists?

Tags: php, wordpress

Why do we need to check function_exists for user defined functions? It looks ok for internal or core PHP functions but if user know and defined a function himself then why do need to check for its existance?

Below is custom user defined function

```
if( !function_exists( 'bia_register_menu' ) ) {
    function bia_register_menu() {
        register_nav_menu('primary-menu', __('Primary Menu'));
    }
    add_action('init', 'bia_register_menu');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Because if you try defining it twice you'll get an error

Comment: @MarkBaker that'd be the answer to this question, I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure you don't register the same function twice, which will cause an error.

You also use `if(function_exists('function_name'))` when you are calling functions defined in plugins. In case you deactivated your plugin, your site will still be functional.

Comment: If I register some function twice (in the same plugin or theme) wouldn't I _want_ an error, in order to notice and correct the obvious design flaw?

Comment: No, WordPress allows you to override some functions, for example, if you're making a child theme ([read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php)).

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111323/26942) on the Wordpress StackExchange clarifies why you should sometimes use `if function_exists` around a function declaration in a *theme*:

> The if function_exists approach allows for a child theme to override the function definition by simply defining the function themselves. Since child theme's functions.php files load first, then they will define the function first and the parent's definition will not get loaded.

I suppose it's analogous to the `protected` keyword in object oriented languages.

However I still wonder whether there would be any need for it around function declarations in *plugins*.

Answer (score 1):

In dynamically loaded files using autoloaders, the file containing the function or class might not have loaded, so you need to check if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you use you're URL to get the function name and call it.
Then we have the following info:

url: http://mysite.com/my/page/

When converting this url into a function name, you would do something like this:

```
implode('_', $myUrlPart); //my_page
```

The output would be "my_page" as string. But if you call this right away and the function does not exist, an error will be shown. This is where the function_exists comes in, take a look:

```
if (function_exists($function_name)) {
    $function_name();  //the function is called
} else {
    //call other function to show HTTP 404 page or something like that
}
```

Does this makes it a little clearer?

Answer (score -1):

Because WordPress is designed so poorly it does not have any proper mechanism for autoloading modules like that, so you need to add safeguards.

Comment: not so much "poorly designed" (although in places it is), more like "originally designed for old PHP versions that couldn't do this sort of thing automatically, and never refactored to catch up with modern best practice".